# Creating a Copy of Site Definition with a different Name

Tags: feature, site-template, list-definition

I have a site definition folder with following structure,

- XML
- default.aspx
- MasterPageabc.master
- masterpageabcajax.master

In XML folder I have "ONET.XML" and I looked into this file, and realized that there isn't any GUID ID in it, just four section and a title, was wondering if changing the title gonna solve the problem for me or not ?

Structure of ONET.XML

```
<xml....>
<project Title ....>
<Navbars>
<ListTemplates>
<DocumentTemplates>
<Configuration>
<Modules>
<serverEmailFooter>
</project>
```

All i see is Title that I can change :S

I changed the Title,   and copied the renamed Folder, ONET.XML(Title of template) and pasted it in

"Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates"

then I renamed the copy "WEBTEPxxxxx" to my Site Definition Name, in folder

"Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\1033\XML"

**I can see the New template in the List, it creates a new site as well, but the created Site is blank, when I checked setting it says, the Master Page isn't right or something.**

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing ID and feature ID did the trick.